# Is there any way to use ComponentDidMount() and ComponentDidUpdate() in Application Customiser Extension in SPFX

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I'm trying to implement a webpart code inside a Extension , I was able to do that . But When i run the code ComponentDidMount() ComponentDidUpdate() are not getting called. Is it possible to implement that or it's not possible? I want to know that.

Feel free to share your knowledge

Thanxxx

Answer (score 0):

From a practical point of view, I don't think you want to run a componentDidUpdate() in an extension unless you have a pretty good if statement.

But I think a componentDidMount should work.

In my customizer.ts file, I create the React Element after the Init

```
const element: React.ReactElement<IAcgBobBotProps> = React.createElement(
                AcgBobBot,
                {
                    webChatToken: this.properties.webChatToken
                }
            );
            ReactDom.render(element, this._bottomPlaceholder.domElement);
```

And I create a component in a new \components\AcgBobBot.tsx TSX file:

```
export default class AcgBobBot extends React.Component<IAcgBobBotProps, IAcgBobBotState> {

    public componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Hi from componentDidMount");
    }
    public render(): React.ReactElement<IAcgBobBotProps> {

    ...
}
```

I, personally, also put my React "web part" into a placeholder, exactly copying the code from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions